# Android touch event list and garbage collector

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection

My game has been stuttering because of the GC and it ranges from 40ms to 140ms.
My game is not creating new objects or anything in the update or render threads so I'm pretty sure my project is clean EXCEPT for one.
In the update method I have a `List<TouchEvents> touchEvents = getTouchEvents();`
I am pretty sure this is what is causing the GC to kick in as it only GC every time I'm moving around as it requires me touching the screen (using the ACTION_MOVE event).
How would I optimize or prevent this?

EDIT:
Now I'm starting to think it has to do with my FPS limit method.
I'm assuming since I am limiting FPS to 30 the GC does not have enough time without interfering with my game.
I came up with this theory after I took the limiter off and ran my game at full 60FPS.
The game goes PERFECTLY SMOOTH when running at 60FPS but not at 30FPS.
Any ideas?

Comment: Are you limiting the *game logic thread*, or the *rendering thread* or maybe *both*?

Comment: To be honest I am not sure. I looked up online how to limit FPS and implemented a method which worked when I tried. Basically in the new thread, I create sleep time and use an "if statement" to check if the sleep time is greater than 33, and if so put the thread to sleep using sleep time as the argument. Then after the if statement I call update and render methods for the current screen.

Comment: Well, to start with; the game will be stuttering in 30 FPS. Is there any reason why you don't want it to run in higher FPS? It sounds like you are limiting both threads, and in that case, both render and game logic will update in 30 FPS. I recommend at least 100 FPS for the game logic loop and you should let the render loop run as fast as possible (which basically means in 60 FPS since Android's screen is V-synced).

Comment: I think I WAS limiting both threads. Only reason I limit the FPS is because I was sure the FPS was going to decrease as I progress in the game development.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I wouldn't recommend capping the fps. Instead, let it run as fast as it can and refer to elapsed time when doing movement and physics.